# Matrix by Vector multiplication using numpy dot product

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, tensor

I have a matrix `m = np.array([[3,4], [5,6], [7,5]])` and a vector `v = np.array([1,2])` and these two tensors can be multiplied.
For multiplication of the above two tensors, no. of columns of `m` must be equal to no. of rows of `v`
The shapes of `m` and `v` are (3,2) and (2,) respectively.
How is the multiplication possible, if `m` has 3 rows and 2 columns whereas `v` has 1 row and 2 columns?

Comment: @I'mahdi this is not a matrix-vector multiplication. This is some kind of numpy magic that multiplies the first column of the matrix by the first component of the vector, and the second column by the second component. It is sometimes convenient, but I don't think that this is what OP is looking for.

Comment: @leleogere, exactly I ask for to find what OP is looking for. Do you know , what op want?

Comment: `m @ v.T`, or `v @ m` `np.eisum('ij,j->i', m, v)`?

Comment: @I'mahdi yes you're right, the question was not very clear. I understood that OP wanted to know why the multiplication was possible and did not raise any error

Comment: @QuangHoang, `v.T` for a 1d array is just `v`.

Comment: Both `np.dot` and `np.matmul` clearly document how they handle the case where an argument is 1d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplication is possible because `v` has only one dimension. Numpy considers it as a vector, so as this vector has 2 components, the matrix vector multiplication is allowed.

However, if you force `v` shape to be 1 row and 2 columns (so 2 dimensions), you will get an (expected) error:

```py
>>> v.reshape(1,2).shape
(1, 2)
>>> np.dot(m, v.reshape(1,2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot
ValueError: shapes (3,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

In order to have a valid multiplication, you need `v` to be 2 rows and 1 column (so you need to transpose it):

```py
>>> np.dot(m, v.reshape(1,2).T)
array([[11],
       [17],
       [17]])
```

And you can see that the shape of the result is `(2,1)`, so 2 rows and one column.

Answer (score 1):

In NumPy, I would recommend not thinking too much about "rows" and "columns"

An array in numpy can have any number of dimensions - you can make 1-dimensional, 2-dimensional or 100-dimensional arrays. A 100-dimensional array doesn't have "rows" and "columns" and neither does a 1-dimensional array.

The simple rule for multiplying 1- or 2-dimensional arrays is: the last axis / dimension of the first array has to have the same size as the first axis / dimension of the second array.

So you can multiply:

- a (3, ) array by a (3, 2) array
- a (3, 2) array by a (2, 3) array
- a (2, 3) array by a (3, ) array